How to Run Multiple PHP Versions Simultaneously on RHEL 8 with Apache?
I am trying to run PHP 8.1, and PHP 8.2 simultaneously on a RHEL 8 server using Apache. Here are the steps I've taken:
Installed PHP Versions:
Used the remi repository to install PHP 8.1, and PHP 8.2.
Commands used:  sudo dnf module install php:8.1
sudo dnf module install php:8.2
Configured Apache:
Created separate virtual host configurations in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ to use different PHP versions.
Switched CLI PHP Versions:
Used sudo alternatives --config php to switch between PHP versions on the command line.
Issues Encountered

Installation Conflicts: Faced conflicts between PHP versions during installation from the remi repository.
Apache Configuration: Apache is not correctly interpreting different PHP versions for separate virtual hosts.
CLI Version Switching: The update-alternatives tool changed the CLI version, but it didn't affect Apache’s handling of PHP versions as expected.

What I Tried

Installed PHP 8.1 and PHP 8.2: Used remi repository on RHEL 8.
Configured Apache: Set different PHP versions for different virtual hosts.
Switched PHP Versions: Used update-alternatives to change CLI PHP version.

What I Expected

Run different PHP versions for different virtual hosts.
Seamless PHP version switching for CLI and Apache.

What Actually Happened

Installation conflicts between PHP versions.

Apache not handling different PHP versions correctly.

CLI version switching didn’t affect Apache.

How to resolve conflicts when installing multiple PHP versions from remi on RHEL 8?

Correct Apache configuration for multiple PHP versions?

Manage and switch CLI PHP versions without affecting Apache?

Best practices for running multiple PHP versions on RHEL 8?


Kindly share the detailed steps which anyone follow to achieve this task.

The "update-alternatives" utility handles symlinks in the file system, that only affects the CLI version of PHP. That is intended and documented behavior. You cannot use it to configure different php versions for different virtual hosts.

Please add the exact configuration for php inside those virtual hosts. We cannot guess that.

What do you actually mean by "Installation conflicts between PHP versions."? Could you install different versions or not?

Keep in mind that you can only install one version of php as a SAPI module (so as a module inside the apache http server). If you want to use different php versions at the same time (for example in different virtual hosts) you cannot do that as modules. Those would be in cinflict. You need to setup one (fast) CGI environment for each additional PHP version and configure that inside your virtual hosts.

" Faced conflicts between PHP versions during installation from the remi repository" - what does that mean? Is there any error message you could share? If you are already facing any problem while installing the packages themselves, this problem looks unrelated to Apache to me

"remi" repository provides Software Collections (SCL) designed for parallel installation of multiple versions
For a proper repository configuration and usage, follow the Wizard instructions
You can also read how I use SCL for my PHP workstation

I actually saw this method of using .htaccess this morning.
httpd.conf
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php80 .php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

.htaccess
<IfModule mod_php8.c>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php80 .php
    Action application/x-httpd-php80 /cgi-bin/php80-cgi
</IfModule>


Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Which part of the original problem is resolved by your configuration? Also, PHP 8.0 is out of support since months and should no longer be used anywhere
